# Select values from Stored Proc to C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SP which looks like this. Trying to capture the select values from SP in C# program

```
CREATE PROC sp_Dosomething
@Prefix nvarchar(2),
@Result nvarchar(8) output
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @LastValue int
DECLARE @FirstValue int

insert into Table1(name,number) values('ssss','123')
@LastValue= @@Identity


insert into Table2(name,number) values('ssss','123')
@FirstValue = @@Identity

Select @LastValue as 'Table1Id', @FirstValue as 'Table2Id'
RETURN True
END

C#

  Response.Redirect("~/Pag1.aspx?Accountid=" + Table1Id+"&ClaimId=" + Table2Id,false);
```

Question:

```
Accountid = Table1Id  = @LastValue This is good

ClaimId= Table2Id = @FirstValue This is always zero
```

Comment: and where is the C# code that calls the sproc?

Comment: Have you tried using `IDENT_CURRENT` to be more table specific instead of `@@identity`?

Comment: You should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the new inserted values, as `@@IDENTITY` can be affected by triggers ran by the `INSERT`. Also, remember that you must use the `SET` statement to make a variable assignment in SQL Server. But to answer the question, I think we should look at the C# code that actually accesses the database.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use `SET` or `SELECT` to set the value of the variables.  you also may want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in case there are any triggers that may change the last identity value:

```
insert into Table1(name,number) values('ssss','123')
SET @LastValue= SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into Table2(name,number) values('ssss','123')
SET @FirstValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to ask, but if your question about how to get output value from SP, after ExecuteReader not before after you do that just read that variable like you normal do with columns.

```
int LastValue = int.press(Reader["LastValue"].ToString());
```

Comment: "int.press" shouldn't be "int.Parse" ?

Comment: yes sorry it's pars :-)